# MySQL search for uppercase in the field then replace with white space

Tags: mysql

I want to search for uppercase in the column then replace this with white space and that letter so there is a space just before the capital letter.

How can I do this in MySQL?

Comment: You may need a udf for this. i.e. Cycle through the characters and perform explicitly. You can detect an Uppercase character using SELECT '<char>' REGEXP('[A-Z]') - returns 1 if the character is uppercase. Or you can dump the table and do it in PHP or somewhere else and put it back in.

Answer (score 0):

You can create special function, example you can check in this article:

http://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/